# MySQL Stored Procedure Design Problem V2. Recusion or Hierarchy?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, recursion, hierarchy

Suppose we have a table named `Connected`, with column `node_1` and `node_2`, both integer type, and some data in it.

It looks like this:

```
`node_1`  `node_2` 
    A        B
    C        D
    B        C
    B        F
    C        W
    D        N
    D        Q

        .
        .
        .  Much much much more
        .
```

What Im trying to do is expand this table, and then collect all relations. For instance, if we can travel from 'A' to 'Q' with path 'A-B-C-D-Q' ( defined by the old table, 'A-B, B-C, C-D, D-Q'), we say that 'A' and 'Q' can be connected, and insert this pair into new table.

Such that, the result table should looks like this:

```
`node_1`  `node_2` 
    A        B
    A        C
    A        D
    A        F
    A        N
    A        Q
    A        W
    B        C
    B        D
    B        F
    B        N
    B        Q    
    B        W
    C        D
    C        N
    C        Q
    C        W
    D        Q
    D        N
```

I appreciate all helps !

> Change the word "Node" to "Group",
>   "connected" to "contains", does it
>   sound more reasonable? Im Sorry for my
>   gramma or any other language related
>   problemssss :)

Comment: If you've got a fair number of nodes, and there's more than just a few hops (on average) between them, you're going to end up with one helluva huge table. Worst-case for profuse linkage (I'm guessing) would be `n!` records.

Answer (score 0):

Same as my other solution, just use ASCII() around the character to the its ascii value in the SELECT.

[MySQL Stored Procedure Design Problem. Recusion or Hierarchy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6602416/mysql-stored-procedure-design-problem-recusion-or-hierarchy/6602533#6602533)

PS. due to our conversation in the other question. Im getting the impression your really content of finding a imperative solution for this. Remember, SQL is a declarative language.